# Unable to revise ContentDocument created in Apex

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument

When I try to create a Content Document (File) in apex, it creates one with no facility to revise or add new version. However if I use the UI to create a file it gives me a link to add new version. Here's the code I use to create the file:

```
    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
     Title = 'Test anonymous 4',
     PathOnClient = 'Test anonymous 4.txt',
     VersionData = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode('Test Anonymous 1'),
     IsMajorVersion = true
    );

insert contentVersion;
```

I'm using API version 42 for my class and page and I'm running this as a system admin. I have tried executing the code in 'execute anonymous' window and it does the same. Is there anything I've missed out?

[image: File created using Apex]

[image: File created using UI]

File created using Apex
File created using UI

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing both the image as same user keeping the same access levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I needed to set the Origin to 'H' on my Content Version to created a revisable file. Very weird.

Comment: this is odd and hard to believe; I've never had to do this

Comment: This is really wired. I also never had to do this, you can see from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code and I can see the upload new version link in the UI.

```
ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
v.versionData = Blob.valueOf('Test String');
v.title = 'Test Upload';
v.pathOnClient ='/mypath.txt';
v.IsMajorVersion = true;
insert v;
System.debug('File Id '+v.id);
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Saroj, your code has the same result as before for me.